# Circumvent fingerprint2.js on a given website

Tags: javascript, fingerprinting

I am not the biggest fan of being tracked on the Internet and fingerprint.js, see here https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2, unfortunately does a very good job of doing so. I have been Googling around for a long time now and I have not found a good solution, which is why I am writing here.

As just disabling JavaScript is not an option as it breaks more or less everything I have tried to look into how to obfuscate the fingerprint so I can change I when I want, as such is it possible for me to hook into a website's JavaScript after it has completed the fingerprint2.js but before it has been sent back to the server? I am unfortunately not well versed in this area so I am not entirely sure that what I propose is possible.

Any other way of effectively circumventing this would also be highly appreciated.

Edit: Alternatively is it possible to override parts of the algorithm?

Answer (score 0):

You can install various Chrome extensions and randomly enable/disable them. I believe part of the fingerprint's hash is based on browser plugins detected. One example is enable/disable ABP to generate a different hash.

Comment: Yeah i know but that does not really solve the problem as they can just look at part of the fingerprint